# PyQt: Window is closed but process still running

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

Just a simple problem (not for me): when I close the window, the program is still running. Here is the code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.Qt import QString
import sys
import sensors
from sensors import *
import threading

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

    signalUpdate = QtCore.pyqtSignal()  # 1 - define a new signal in mainwindow class
                                        # 2 -connect this signal to the update() function
                                        #emit signal

    #main window
    def __init__(self):
        #vars for core temp and name
        self.tempValue = 0
        self.name = '0'

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Title here")        
        self.setFixedSize(250, 150)

        self.home()

    #make widgets (progressBar and labe)
    def home(self):
        self.prgB = QtGui.QProgressBar(self)
        self.prgB.setGeometry(20, 20, 210, 20)
        #self.prgB.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create("motif"))#stles -> motif, Plastique, Windows

        self.lbl = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.lbl.setGeometry(60, 40, 210, 20)

        self.signalUpdate.connect(self.update)  #connect this signal to the update() function

        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(self.prgB)
        lay.addWidget(self.lbl)
        self.setLayout(lay)

        self.tmp()
        self.show()

    #update() to update label and progressbar values
    def update(self):
        textas = ('%s : %.1f' % (self.name, self.tempValue))
        self.lbl.setText(str(textas + ' C'))
        self.prgB.setFormat(QString.number(self.tempValue)+ ' C')
        self.prgB.setValue(self.tempValue)

    #temp() to get chip data from sensors (temp, name etc)
    def tmp(self):
        sensors.init()
        try:
            for chip in sensors.iter_detected_chips():
                #print (chip)
                #print('Adapter:', chip.adapter_name)
                for feature in chip:
                    if feature.label == 'Physical id 0':
                        self.tempValue = feature.get_value()
                        self.name = feature.label
                        #print ('%s (%r): %.1f' % (feature.name, feature.label, feature.get_value()))

                        threading.Timer(2.0, self.tmp).start()

                        self.signalUpdate.emit()    #emit signal
                #print
        finally:
            sensors.cleanup()

def run():
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_X11InitThreads)    
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = MainWindow()        
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Why is that happening, and how to fix it? (I was trying to research on google and yes there are many forums with same question but I get no luck so far to fix it).

EDIT: problem is still not fixed, can someone show/tell how to stop threading.Time on program exit? Please :)

Comment: `import sensors; from sensors import *` <-- are you sure?

Comment: no Im not :) this one is fixed and thanks. and do you have any idea about main problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't know the first thing about Qt or python GUIs in general. That just stuck out to me:) I mean, I suspect it to be related to threading, I can imagine that to spawn a process that sticks around, otherwise I don't know.

Comment: yea I comment threading and everything is ok... looks like I need to change threading.Timer(2.0, self.tmp).start to something else.

Comment: You should put something into the `finally:` block after the `sensors.cleanup()`, that will kill that timer thread. I'm unfamiliar with threading, so I can't tell you how, but it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: hehe 'put something' you mean like stop timer? I did but still the same

Comment: @Andras Deak I did threading.Timer(2.0, self.tmp).cancel() in `finally:` but timer still ticking

Comment: I suspect that you need to use the same `Timer` instance. So set something like `self.timer = threading.Timer(2.0, self.tmp); self.timer.start()` when you start it, and later call `self.timer.cancel()` in the finally block (or in the widget's `closeEvent()` method as Schollii suggested; as I said I'm not familiar with these tools).

Comment: @Andras Deak thanks, I did Schollii method and looks like its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the timer's cancel() method in your widget's (overridden) closeEvent() method:

```
def tmp(self):
    ...
    self.timer = threading.Timer(2.0, self.tmp)
    self.timer.start()
    self.signalUpdate.emit()    #emit signal

def closeEvent(self):
    self.timer.cancel()
```

I've tested that this works:

- without the threading, app exits;
- with the threading.Timer, but without the timer cancel, app never exits;
- with the timer cancel, app exits

Comment: not sure I did right or not, but as you said I tried put threading .stop()/cancel() inside run function but no luck so far

Comment: @MariusValentavicius I tested and it works, I added the code to show how I did it

Comment: thanks for your time. I did what you tell me to do but I getting `TypeError: CcloseEvent() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`. Ahh well maybe Im still sleepy (5.53 am now :) ). will try to fix after work. Thanks.

Comment: `def closeEevent(self, event):` and it is working! :) thank you

Comment: Excellent. I tested with PyQt5 so event must be optional arg in v5.